# Create user interface with multiple pages stacked on top of each other in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, user-interface

at the moment i am trying to get into WPF programming. For that i want to create a small application with a hopefully decent looking user interface. But now i am running into a problem. First of all, my user interface should look something like this:
[My interface so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n92pi.jpg)

I thought about creating one main window with multiple buttons to choose what you want to do. When i press one of these buttons, all controls for this should be visible on the right.
So for every button there should be a new "window" on the right side, where the darkgray panel with the black line is.

My first solution is to create a new window (.xaml-file) for every button, which could be selected. But i ran into the following problem. Everytime i click on my first window the second window will be brought to the background. I already fixxed it when i am moving the first window, that the second window will be set to a new position and also will be the in the foreground.
Setting the .TopMost Property on my second window is not an option, cause i dont like it to be over my toolbar.

So my question is:
Is there a better way to create my interface than having multiple windows which are only opened when a button is pressed? But i might create more buttons, so i would like to have something what is easily extendible.

If this is the only good option for keeping the overview over all the controls. Can i prevent the first window getting into the foreground when i dont press a button on it?

If there is any additional information you need, please leave a comment.
Thanks for every answer!
Have a nice day,
Heenne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered a TabControl rather than buttons to select each "window". Whatever you do I'd definitely avoid having a separate window for each as that would be very messy.

What I'd do is create each frame as a UserControl not a Window in a seperate xaml as you suggest (with associated xaml.cs and so on).  You can then put that user control where ever you like - in a tab control for example.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Page1"
    ...>

  <Grid>    
      <!--your controls here-->
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

then in your main window you might have

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
        <ns:Page1 />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

ns will be the namespace for your user control

Or you could simple define it in the main window xaml and set the Visibility to visible when you click the button.  Ideally you'd do this via a binding to a ViewModel class set as your DataContext

```
<ns:Page1 Visibility="{Binding page1Visible}"/>
```

Or alternatively have a content present

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
```

Then set CurrentPage to be an instance of your user control when the button is clicked.

There are many ways to skin a cat as they say.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I would like to upvote it, but i´m not at the 15 rep mark.
I will try to do it the TabControl-way first and later try to create my own design with the ContentPresenter or so... i will see.

Comment: No probs. I've upvoted your question to help your reputation. :)

Comment: Oh, thank you! But now i got another request. Could you help me with the solution using the TabControl? I got this so far: I created a new project with my mainwindow which contains the TabControl. Then i added a UserControl named "ManualCalculator.xaml" to my project. Am i understanding this right, that they are both in the same namespace? Because you created an extra namespace for the user control... Because when i want to create an extra namespace, the new UserControll doesnt show up.
EDIT: ah well, i searched for the namespace ProjectName.UserclassName ... that was the mistake

Answer (score 0):

possible approaches

1} one main window with a `Frame` where a new `Page` will be loaded into that frame after menu button click

it is simple to create a specialized Page (in separate file) for each app function

related article [Navigation with MVVM](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/) in Rachel Lim blog

2} one main window with multiple tabs (similar to browsers). Tabs can be predefined or can be added on demand (multiple tabs for each app function, if that is supported?)

both are variants of - MDI, Multiple document interface